# Добавление DataGrid виджета в Monodevelop

Tags: c#, ui, datagrid, monodevelop, виджет

Я знаю, что в MVS(*Microsoft Visual Studio*) есть такой компонент формы, как **DataGridView**, который позволяет добавлять таблицу на форму со своими параметрами.

В MonoDevelop, как я понял, немного иной принцип построения графическго интерфейса. получается, в Monodevelop *существуют раздельно контейнеры*, в которые нужно вкладывать виджеты, *и сами виджеты.*

Так ж в MonoDevelop в окне с виджетами есть кнопочка с "+", которая позволяет *добавлять сторонние виджеты*. После нажатия на кнопку появляется *FileEntry*, в котором предлагается "**Add Assembly**". Как я понял, сторонние виджеты должны представлять собой собранные *.dll* файлы. Но поиск в гугле не помог мне найти готовый DataGrid.

Так же пытался добавлять через **NuGet** пакты. Информации о том, как использовать пакеты в виджетах не нашел.

Так же искал в стандартных завсимостях, которые можно подключить, и нашел там **Windows.Forms.DataVisualzation**... Но там тем более сложнее разобраться.

И вот есть вопрос - как можно добавить такой же **DataGrid**, как в *MVS*. **Костыль через NodeView или TreeView не подходит.**

P.S. Уже прошло около полугода, как я пытаюсь решить ту задачу.

Comment: MonoDevelop это не `Windows.Forms` это `Gtk`. И в Gtk нет абсолютного аналога DataGrid.

Comment: @Vasek - А готовая реализация DataGrid существует? Чтобы можно было импортировать в раздел виджетов. Ведь такая функция(добавления сторонних виджетов) существует. Не представляю, как для этого оформить запрос в Google, ведь он выводит - показывает, как их сделать самому. Но я видел, что она существует на гитхабе разработчика. Но для импорта оно не подходит.